# Camera intent not working: it enters catch block and says "could not create file!"

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, kotlin

problem in opening camera intent in android

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.Toast

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 0
    lateinit var imageFilePath:String


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->

        try{
            val imageFile=createImageFile()
            val callCameraIntent= Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            if(callCameraIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)!=null)
            {
                val authorities=packageName+".fileprovider"
                val imageUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,authorities,imageFile)
                callCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri)
                startActivityForResult(callCameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE )
            }

        }
        catch (e:Exception)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Could not create" +
                    " file!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        }
    }
```

// MY ACTIVITYRESULT FUNCTION

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when(requestCode)
        {
            CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE -> {

                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    photoImageView.setImageBitmap(setScaledBitmap())
                }

            }
            else -> {

                Toast.makeText(this,"Unrecognized " +
                        "result code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

// MY ACTIVITYRESULT FUNCTION

```
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun createImageFile(): File
    {
        val timestamp=SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",Locale.US).format(Date())
        val imageFileName = "JPEG_"+timestamp + "_"
        val storageDir=getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

        if(!storageDir.exists())
        {
            storageDir.mkdirs()
        }

        val imageFile= createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir)
        imageFilePath=imageFile.absolutePath

        return imageFile
    }


    fun setScaledBitmap():Bitmap{

        val imageViewWith =photoImageView.width
        val imageViewHeight =photoImageView.height

        val bmOptions=BitmapFactory.Options()
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds=true
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath,bmOptions)
        val bitmapWidth=bmOptions.outWidth
        val bitmapHeight=bmOptions.outHeight

        val scaleFactor= Math.min(bitmapWidth/imageViewWith,bitmapHeight/imageViewHeight)
        bmOptions.inSampleSize=scaleFactor

        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds=false

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath,bmOptions)


    }


}




// MANIFEST


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hi.httpwww.hi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="$(applicationId).fileprovider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"/>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>



// filepaths.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="intent_images"
        path="Pictures"/>

</paths>
```

I am facing problem in above code. When I start my activity it it says could not open file. Is that correct behaviour or I am doing anything wrong? without calling on destroy of my activity it is again coming inside on create.Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: at last i have added few lines from another file

Comment: have you given permission from settings in device

Comment: You have to request premissions on runtime from Marshmallow and new APIs. Please refer to my post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48109551/1117834

Comment: `storageDir.mkdirs()`. Check the return value and do not continue if it fails. It fails now and you are complaining about a file that does not get created. Instead you should mention the failed directory creation. Further your problem has nothing to do with a camera intent. Wrong subject.